# The movieclip contains various examples of names

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, movieclip

How do I loaded MovieClips in the position of the mouse with a different name on each click? or I have to make several different MovieClips to laod?

please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
var counter:int = 0;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);

function click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); // Or new YourExportedLibraryClip();

    mc.name = 'mc_' + (counter++);
    mc.x = stage.mouseX;
    mc.y = stage.mouseY;

    stage.addChild(mc);
}
```

Comment: how do I call this MovieClips again?
example for hitTesObject